# Is a Libyan visa issued before the revolution still valid?

Tags: visas, libya

A guy I'm having some beers with here in Romania was telling me he has a visa for Libya but doesn't know if he can still use it.

He applied for and received the visa before the Arab spring and it's valid for two years.

Now the revolution in Libya has pretty much settled down but it's no longer the same government.

Can my friend still use the same visa or will he have to get a new visa?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your friend will need a new visa to enter Libya. All old visas are considered invalid and no longer accepted.

Please note, Visa requirements have also changed. Some nationalities do not require visa to enter Libya now (while they needed before the revolution) and some do require a visa now (while they did not require one before the revolution). So let your friend ask the local Libyan embassy.

Comment: Do you have any official reference for this information?

Comment: No, I read it in news paper.. and I am sure there were many workers who came back to Libya with the old visas and were refused to enter. it was all over the news papers some time ago.

Comment: http://www.visahq.com/ on this site you can find more information. But the best way is really to ask a Libyan embassy